# Merging and rearranging xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-grouping

I am using XSLT for converting a XML derived from web and convert the same on the fly into the target xml file denoted as output .
I am still unable to do so even after trying a lot , Can anyone please help me out with this conversion .

**Source XML**

```
<allocelement>
    <hd1>12</hd1>
    <hd2>14</hd2>
    <hd3>87</hd3>
        <alc>1</alc>
    <amount>4587</amount>
    <code>1111</code>
</allocelement>
<alloclement>
        <hd1>12</hd1>
    <hd2>14</hd2>
    <hd3>87</hd3>
    <alc>2</alc>
    <amount>80000</amount>
    <code>1111</code>
</alloclement>
<alloclement>
    <hd1>875</hd1>
    <hd2>455</hd2>
    <hd3>455</hd3>
    <alc>2</alc>
    <amount>80000</amount>
    <code>1112</code>
 </alloclement>
```

***Output Desired***

```
<allocelement>
    <Codeheader>
    <code>1111</code>
        <hd1>12</hd1>
        <hd2>14</hd2>
        <hd3>87</hd3>
                <alc>1</alc>
                    <amount>4587</amount>
                <alc>2</alc>
                    <amount>80000</amount>
    </codeHeader>
        <CodeHeader>
    <code>1112</code>
        <hd1>875</hd1>
        <hd2>455</hd2>
        <hd3>455</hd3>
            <alc>2</alc>
              <amount>80000</amount>
    </CodeHeader>
</allocelement>
```

The Grouping is on the basis of Code,[hd1,hd2,hd3] such that the different elements within  which have the same  Code and [hd1,hd2,hd3] will be merged and only show fields which are different viz. the  and . 
Also I am using xslt 1.0 .

Comment: Please post what you've done so far in XSLT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A significantly shorter and simpler XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kCodeByVal" match="code" use="."/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <allocelement>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </allocelement>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="allocelement"/>

 <xsl:template match=
  "allocelement
    [generate-id(code) = generate-id(key('kCodeByVal', code)[1])]">
  <code><xsl:value-of select="code"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select=
    "node()[not(self::code)]
    | key('kCodeByVal', code)/../*[self::alc or self::amount]"/>
  </code>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (a single top element wrapping the provided XML fragment):

```
<t>
    <allocelement>
        <hd1>12</hd1>
        <hd2>14</hd2>
        <hd3>87</hd3>
        <alc>1</alc>
        <amount>4587</amount>
        <code>1111</code>
    </allocelement>
    <allocelement>
        <hd1>12</hd1>
        <hd2>14</hd2>
        <hd3>87</hd3>
        <alc>2</alc>
        <amount>80000</amount>
        <code>1111</code>
    </allocelement>
    <allocelement>
        <hd1>875</hd1>
        <hd2>455</hd2>
        <hd3>455</hd3>
        <alc>2</alc>
        <amount>80000</amount>
        <code>1112</code>
    </allocelement>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<allocelement>
   <code>1111<hd1>12</hd1>
      <hd2>14</hd2>
      <hd3>87</hd3>
      <alc>1</alc>
      <amount>4587</amount>
      <alc>2</alc>
      <amount>80000</amount>
   </code>
   <code>1112<hd1>875</hd1>
      <hd2>455</hd2>
      <hd3>455</hd3>
      <alc>2</alc>
      <amount>80000</amount>
   </code>
</allocelement>
```

**Explanation**: Proper use of the **[Muenchian grouping method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)**.

---

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution -- again shorter, and much more importantly -- syntactically and semantically correct**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
  <allocelement>
   <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="code">
     <code><xsl:value-of select="code"/>
        <xsl:sequence select=
        "node()[not(self::code)]
        | current-group()/*[self::alc or self::amount]"/>
  </code>
   </xsl:for-each-group>
  </allocelement>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**UPDATE**: The OP has changed the requirements for the outpu.

**Here is the corresponding modified XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

     <xsl:key name="kCodeByVal" match="code" use="."/>

     <xsl:template match="/*">
      <allocelement>
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </allocelement>
     </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="allocelement"/>

     <xsl:template match=
      "allocelement
        [generate-id(code) = generate-id(key('kCodeByVal', code)[1])]">
      <codeHeader>
       <code><xsl:value-of select="code"/></code>
         <xsl:copy-of select=
         "node()[not(self::code)]
         | key('kCodeByVal', code)/../*[self::alc or self::amount]"/>
      </codeHeader>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: it is shorter also because you "hardcoded" the names of nodes that are not duplicates. Also, can you tell me where my solution isn't syntactically or semantically correct? :)

Comment: @PavelVeller: Your XSLT solution uses an undefined key and causes compilation error. One needs to provide the complete transformation -- not only this eliminates any possible confusion, but it also shows the true size of the code.

Comment: @PavelVeller: The solution is shorter (as it should be), because I am using the `current-group()` function -- as everyone would. Also, all element-siblings of a node in this case can be selected with a much shorter expression -- just `../*[not self::itsName]`

Comment: point taken. still, your solution is bound to those tag names. just add `<something>a</something>` to the "second" occurrence of the `allocelement` with `<code>1111</code>` and see how it's not making it into the result tree. I tried to build a more generic algorithm so that's why I used grouping for those nodes too. Agree that your solution is much more elegant when it comes to dealing with groups and I will have to practice those techniques more :)

Comment: @PavelVeller: Good. As for my solution being specific, I think that in many cases a specific solution is just what's needed, because we cannot guess correctly all possible contexts of the OP, and because often adding generality can confuse the OP and the readers, when at the same time there is a short and easy to understand specific solution for their specific problem. Probably the right approach is first to provide the simple specific solution and only then start giving generalizations.

Comment: thanks guys I almost reached the solution using Dimitre's solution , well I perceived it to b simpler to understand at a novice level .. one more help dimitre , I modified the output a lil bit can u guide me with the changes in xsl I need to do thanks a lot for ur help

Comment: @Manks: You are welcome. I will have a look at your modifications when I am back from work (8hrs from now). Would you, please, care to *accept* the answer?

Comment: @ Dimitre : Could u pls have a look at the modified output and guide me with the changes in the xsl.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume your input XML has a `root` node that wraps it all to make a well formed document. I would also assume all `allocelement` are spelled right (you have some spelled as `alloclement`). I would also assume you want to remove the duplicates identified by the tag name and its text value.

With **XSLT 1.0**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="code" match="allocelement/code" use="."/>

    <xsl:key name="code-sibling" 
             match="allocelement/*[name() != 'code']" 
             use="concat(parent::*/code, '|', name(), '|', .)"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="copy">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="root/allocelement[1]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="allocelement">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates 
                    select="(. | following-sibling::allocelement)/code
                                [generate-id() = generate-id(key('code', .)[1])]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="code">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>

            <xsl:apply-templates 
                    select="key('code', .)/(preceding-sibling::* | following-sibling::*)
                                [generate-id() = 
                                 generate-id(key('code-sibling', concat(parent::*/code, '|', name(), '|', .))[1])]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to:

```
<root>
    <allocelement>
        <hd1>12</hd1>
        <hd2>14</hd2>
        <hd3>87</hd3>
        <alc>1</alc>
        <amount>4587</amount>
        <code>1111</code>
    </allocelement>
    <allocelement>
        <hd1>12</hd1>
        <hd2>14</hd2>
        <hd3>87</hd3>
        <alc>2</alc>
        <amount>80000</amount>
        <code>1111</code>
    </allocelement>
    <allocelement>
        <hd1>875</hd1>
        <hd2>455</hd2>
        <hd3>455</hd3>
        <alc>2</alc>
        <amount>80000</amount>
        <code>1112</code>
     </allocelement>
</root>
```

produces:

```
<root>
   <allocelement>
      <code>1111<hd1>12</hd1>
         <hd2>14</hd2>
         <hd3>87</hd3>
         <alc>1</alc>
         <amount>4587</amount>
         <alc>2</alc>
         <amount>80000</amount>
      </code>
      <code>1112<hd1>875</hd1>
         <hd2>455</hd2>
         <hd3>455</hd3>
         <alc>2</alc>
         <amount>80000</amount>
      </code>
   </allocelement>
</root>
```

Here's how it works. The default route is the [identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform). We interrupt at first `allocelement` and send the transform down a different route. We let it copy the unique `code` element (uniqueness identified by the text value of the element) with its value and then apply templates on all preceding/following siblings of all `code` nodes sharing the same value. These will be child nodes to the `code` node now. We then call the identity transform for those siblings that are unique (belong to the `code` of the same value, have same name and same text value).

One note. [MIXED content](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-mixed-content) is never a good idea. See if you really need to mix the text value and child nodes under the `code`.

With **XSLT 2.0** you could stay away from `generate-id()`s:

```
<xsl:template match="allocelement">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="(. | following-sibling::allocelement)/code" group-by=".">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="code">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>

        <xsl:for-each-group select="key('code', .)/(preceding-sibling::* | following-sibling::*)"
                            group-by="concat(parent::*/code, '|', name(), '|', .)">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each-group> 
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Why are you using the `key()` function in the XSLT 2.0 solution -- undefined at that?

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, just because it was there anyway in the 1.0 version. I just wanted to illustrate the `xsl:for-each-group`

Comment: Pavel Veller: You may want to read about the `current-group()` function, then. Nobody uses `key()` together with `xsl:for-each-group` and one of the main use-cases for the latter was to avoid the need of using keys.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev thanks for the hint but I guess we're talking about different things. I used `key()` as part of the selector only because it was giving me all the `code` nodes that shared the same value with the current one. Anyway, this argument is of no benefit to the person who asked a question here :)

Comment: Pavel Veller: Yes, and a good XSLT 2.0 way to select all these `code` nodes is by using the `current-group()` function -- you may want to get accustomed to using it.

Comment: An argument that actually is concentrated on knowledge definitely helps ... Anyways thanks a lot folks ...this was my first ever question on stack exchange and my experience was gud ..thanks

Comment: @Manks: You are welcome. In case you found these answers useful, what about *accepting* one of them (by clicking the check-mark next to the best answer)? :) Hint: Later, when you have accumulated 50 points reputation, you can further upvote any or both of these answers.